# Why is $VAR(My)=M VAR (y) M^T$?

Tags: references, least-squares, matrix, covariance-matrix

This question is in the context of ordinary least squares.

If $M$ is a matrix, and $y$ is a vector of random variables, then I have been told that  $$VAR(My)=M VAR (y) M^T$$

I know that $Var(y)=E[(y-Ey)(y-Ey)^T]$, but I don't know how to get the above result.

**How do we get the above result, and secondarily, what is a good resource for me to learn about Expectations and variance in the context of matrices and vectors rather than scalars, and about matrix calculus (as this is also used in OLS)?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To ease the notation, let $E(Y)=\mu$.
\begin{align*}
Var(MY) &= E\{(MY-M\mu)(MY-M\mu)^T\}\\
&= E\{M(Y-\mu)(Y-\mu)^TM^T\}\\
&= ME\{(Y-\mu)(Y-\mu)^T\}M^T\\
&= MVar(Y)M^T
\end{align*}
As per Michael's suggestion, this uses linearity of expectation.

Comment: IMO you skipped the crucial step (invoking the linearity of expectations to get $\mathbb{E}[MY] = M\mathbb{E}[Y]$...